# Person table with list of friends (=persons) field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

New to database design. What i'm trying to do is transform a java object called "Persons" into a MySQL schema.

Usual values are fields like first/last name, adresses etc. with key=numeric id. But each person also knows other persons - in java i just have a list of "Person" as a member variable, but how would i go about this in MySQL where i cannot just add a known persons field with a list of person IDs ?

Table Person:

```
ID  | FName  | LName  | Street | ... | Knows
int | String | String | String | ... |  ???
```

Do i need to create a separate table "Who knows whom" ?

```
 person1 | person2 | Knows
 Person  | Person  | boolean
```

Or is there a better way, if possible using javax.persistence with annotations on the java objects?

Comment: Reference person-known has M:N type, so it needs in intermediate link table. This table structure is dependent by the fact does the knowledge is symmetric or not (if A knows B does B knows A always).

Comment: The client-side solution is wrong. The solutions when all references are stored in one field (CSV, XML, JSON) is wrong too. I'd recommend do not ever think about them...

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the "client-side solution is wrong" part. I see its inconvenient if i want to save my objects into a database. But its not wrong, without SQL access the program using the object does exactly what its supposed to do...

Comment: If the performance does not matter to you, then getting the packed objects from the database and processing them on the client can be a suitable solution, of course...

Comment: I would like to get good performance, so using serialized arrayList blobs would only be the last resort. So i need to change my objects to fit the sql database format if i want to use annotations to create my tables, correct?

Comment: That's a many:many mapping.  Use it.

Comment: Thank you, just looked at the many to many and one to many annotations that will create the required tables for me, so i can still have a good database structure without serialized list blob, but don't need to change all objects to not exclude lists. If you want to put up the one to '@OneToMany' '@ManyToMany' etc. annotations as an answer i would accept it